# Unable to display the default page of Apache2 (LAMP)

Tags: apache, lamp

I was using WAMP previously and I have decided to use LAMP now. I followed the following tutorial on youtube to setup a LAMP server.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrGD2X-sDQY

However, I am unable to display the welcome page of apache2 in the video.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrGD2X-sDQY&feature=player_detailpage#t=1045s

I doubt if the port 80 is occupied by WAMP even I have uninstalled the WAMP in Control Panel.

Is there any way to free the port 80 or is there any other problems which stop me from displaying the welcome page of apache2?

Thanks very much!